# Centos 7 server with Nginx reports errors when updating packages

Tags: nginx, centos7, installation, packages, webmin

I have a CentOS 7 VM with Nginx installed. I use Webmin to administer the server.

It normally installs updates automatically, but the nginx update failed so I tried to manually do the update. It returns this:

```
Installing package(s) with command /bin/yum -y install nginx ..
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.netsite.dk
 * epel: mirror.netsite.dk
 * extras: mirror.netsite.dk
 * updates: mirror.netsite.dk
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package nginx.x86_64 1:1.20.1-9.el7 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: nginx(abi) = 1.20.1 for package: 1:nginx-mod-mail-1.20.1-9.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: nginx(abi) = 1.20.1 for package: 1:nginx-mod-stream-1.20.1-9.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: nginx(abi) = 1.20.1 for package: 1:nginx-mod-http-perl-1.20.1-9.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: nginx(abi) = 1.20.1 for package: 1:nginx-mod-http-image-filter-1.20.1-9.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: nginx(abi) = 1.20.1 for package: 1:nginx-mod-http-xslt-filter-1.20.1-9.el7.x86_64
---> Package nginx.x86_64 1:1.20.2-1.el7.ngx will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 1:nginx-mod-http-perl-1.20.1-9.el7.x86_64 (@epel)
           Requires: nginx(abi) = 1.20.1
           Removing: 1:nginx-1.20.1-9.el7.x86_64 (@epel)
               nginx(abi) = 1.20.1
           Updated By: 1:nginx-1.20.2-1.el7.ngx.x86_64 (nginx)
               Not found
Error: Package: 1:nginx-mod-stream-1.20.1-9.el7.x86_64 (@epel)
           Requires: nginx(abi) = 1.20.1
           Removing: 1:nginx-1.20.1-9.el7.x86_64 (@epel)
               nginx(abi) = 1.20.1
           Updated By: 1:nginx-1.20.2-1.el7.ngx.x86_64 (nginx)
               Not found
Error: Package: 1:nginx-mod-mail-1.20.1-9.el7.x86_64 (@epel)
           Requires: nginx(abi) = 1.20.1
           Removing: 1:nginx-1.20.1-9.el7.x86_64 (@epel)
               nginx(abi) = 1.20.1
           Updated By: 1:nginx-1.20.2-1.el7.ngx.x86_64 (nginx)
               Not found
Error: Package: 1:nginx-mod-http-image-filter-1.20.1-9.el7.x86_64 (@epel)
           Requires: nginx(abi) = 1.20.1
           Removing: 1:nginx-1.20.1-9.el7.x86_64 (@epel)
               nginx(abi) = 1.20.1
           Updated By: 1:nginx-1.20.2-1.el7.ngx.x86_64 (nginx)
               Not found
Error: Package: 1:nginx-mod-http-xslt-filter-1.20.1-9.el7.x86_64 (@epel)
           Requires: nginx(abi) = 1.20.1
           Removing: 1:nginx-1.20.1-9.el7.x86_64 (@epel)
               nginx(abi) = 1.20.1
           Updated By: 1:nginx-1.20.2-1.el7.ngx.x86_64 (nginx)
               Not found
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
.. install failed!
```

I have tried to run the rpm command suggested - and then redo the package update. But that made no difference.

I also tried to install the 19 other packages - they all installed correctly. Then I retried Nginx - but it still fails with the same error... I have also tried to disable the nginx repo and the epel repo in turn (in case it was a clash between the two repos) - but it made no difference.

Does anyone know what caused this issue - and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

/John

Comment: It looks to me like the new packages can't be found on the repository server. Did you check that the mirror is still valid?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and it looks like the same scenario (CentOS 7, EPEL, Nginx repo, same packages are 'Not found').

Comment: I'm having the same issue, with the same setup (CentOS 7, EPEL, nginx repo). My errors are identical. Our C7 servers stopped being able to upgrade on Nov 16, which is [when the nginx repo added 1.20.2](http://nginx.org/packages/centos/7/x86_64/RPMS/). The errors suggest (to me, at least) that `yum update` is attempting to update nginx to 1.20.2, but the EPEL-provided nginx packages (e.g. [nginx-mod-mail](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/nginx-mod-mail-1.20.1-9.el7.x86_64.rpm.html)) have an nginx requirement of 1.20.1 (see "Requires"), and so the dependencies can't be resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've solved this for my system, though my solution may not be applicable to everyone, depending on whether or not you use the `nginx-*` modules that are causing the dependency issues.

---

My solution was to **remove `nginx-mod-http-perl`, `nginx-mod-stream`, `nginx-mod-mail`, `nginx-mod-http-image-filter`, and `nginx-mod-http-xslt-filter`**, and I was then able to `yum upgrade` to get the latest nginx version.

*Edited to add*: In addition to removing those packages, I updated `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo` to have `exclude=nginx*`, to prevent `@epel`-provided nginx packages from being reinstalled.

This worked for me because I don't actually use the functionality provided by those packages; I have a hunch they are installed by Webmin (which, like the OP, I'm also using) to support some of the features that it *can* provide.

If you are using functionality these modules provide, then I think the solution, at least for now, is to **disable the nginx repo**, and re-enable it if/when `@epel` releases compatible modules. If you do this, you will not have any nginx upgrades available, since there's no 1.20.2 available on `@epel`.

---

The core problem seems to be that you (and I) have `nginx-1.20.1-9.el7.x86_64 (@epel)` installed, but both `@epel` and `nginx` repos enabled.

On/around Nov 16, the `nginx` repo released `nginx-1.20.2`, and so yum is now trying to update to that version. However, there are no corresponding `1.20.2` updates for the various `nginx-*` modules installed (either on `@epel` or on `nginx`) and so they couldn't be udpated. Those modules also require `nginx(abi) = 1.20.1`, which is the one that `@epel` provides (but that `nginx` does *not* appear to provide) and so the dependency check failed.

*Sidenote*: in our case, we **did** have the `nginx`-provided core package installed at one point in time, and it was replaced at some point with the `@epel` version - this is from yum logs:

```
# zgrep -h nginx.x86 /var/log/yum.log-202* /var/log/yum.log
Apr 22 03:55:37 Updated: nginx.x86_64 1:1.18.0-1.el7.ngx
Oct 30 09:27:11 Updated: nginx.x86_64 1:1.18.0-2.el7.ngx
Apr 21 08:48:33 Updated: nginx.x86_64 1:1.20.0-1.el7.ngx
May 26 04:20:28 Updated: nginx.x86_64 1:1.20.1-1.el7.ngx
Jun 18 06:46:31 Installed: nginx.x86_64 1:1.20.1-2.el7
Oct 27 04:51:03 Updated: nginx.x86_64 1:1.20.1-9.el7
```

On June 18 the `.ngx` package was replaced with the one provided by `@epel`. This may or may not be relevant to the problem at hand.

Comment: Hi @joel - thanks for your update. I tried to uninstall those modules as well (had to  ignore dependencies) - and then the update succeeded.

Comment: I just went through the same process outlined here. Thanks!

I added "exclude=nginx*" to my EPEL repo and removed nginx. After that I removed nginx using 'yum remove nginx' which removed my modules as well.

I was able to find some of the modules I was using in the main nginx repo (https://centos.pkgs.org/7/nginx-x86_64/) but a few aren't there. Now I'm missing "nginx-mod-mail" and "nginx-mod-stream". The new format is "nginx-module-{module name}" by the way. Also, remember your old nginx config is saved as /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.rpmsave

Answer (score 1):

```
yum remove nginx-mod-http-perl*
yum remove nginx-mod-stream*
yum remove nginx-mod-mail*
yum remove nginx-mod-http-image-filter*
yum remove nginx-mod-http-xslt-filter*
```

also don't panic nginx-all-modules will be removed

https://yum-info.contradodigital.com/view-package/epel/nginx-all-modules/